# Forward Scattering

Tags: materials

I have solved the problems of rayleigh scattering and thanks to help of members here, created a new ring with buggy tools. Now I am curious about one more thing.

Is it possible to simulate forward scattering? Planet rings are brighter when viewed from the opposite side of the light source. I tried using the SSS shader but it does not replicate the effect. I would try using a volume shader (since anisotropy controls back versus forward scattering) but 2D textures do not influence volume density (I am using a radio occultation map of saturn's rings as the alpha texture).

Comment: Maybe try mixing your other nodes with a `Emission` shader and using the `Is Shadow Ray` input for the mix value. This would mean it would emit light on the dark/shadow side of the rings.

Comment: My goal was to have this scene of Saturn and its moons be as physically accurate as possible. But I will try the emission shader as a last resort.

Comment: You could try *adding* (not mixing) a *translucent shader* to the current material setup for the rings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the node setup is use for saturn's rings :
[image: node setup!]
Textures come from [here](http://www.mmedia.is/~bjj/data/s_rings/index.html).

Comment: That's very helpful. I went through more of that guys page after visiting your link and the rings also change color depending on viewing angle. The anisotropy shader should help there. Thanks!